Sitecore Sxa Wild card implementation
I have a bunch of news items created under a tenant/home/news as tenant/home/news/<news-items> in a Sitecore sxa. I am trying to convert it to buckets and is successful. Now the URLs are coming as
tenant-URL/news/<bucket folders>/<news-items> .
So I wanted to omit, the  in URL's, and display this news item as tenant-URL/news/<news-items> . For this, I just added a wild card page(*)(created from sample page) and added all the bucket-folders and  news-items to be the child of this wildcard page(*).
As a result when I hit
tenant-URL/news/<news-items>

the wildcard page(*) is being displayed.
Also, this news page list out all the  and if any of this items are clicked to view the news items URL looks to be as tenant-URL/news/,-w-,/<bucket-folders>/<news-items>,
This is my first time trying to implement the Wildcard. Please advice me how to achieve what I am trying.
TIA
